# GeoServer CSS how to force labels onto map where boundaries are tight or narrow

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

I'd like to force labels onto the map.  For instance, the Western Mountain label ideally could go just above Washington State.  I have tried various permutations, but I cannot seem to get the labels to display.

```
* {
  label: [REGION];
  font-size: 6;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Were you able to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `label-fit-goodness` property, should help:
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/css/properties.html

Comment: That property did not help my situation.  I tried numerous values and just get the one label to work, but the others do not display.

Comment: Did you try setting it to zero?

Comment: Thanks.  I did try 0.

Comment: Then I suggest opening a bug report against GeoServer, including both the dataset in question, and the style used.